# Ubuntu 16.04 detects wireless during trial, but not after install

Tags: wireless, system-installation, 16.04

While installing Ubuntu 16.04 I am able to use my wireless adapter (ROSEWILL RNX-N180UBEV2), as soon as I restart after installing there are no wireless adapters visible. This happens for both Ubuntu and Ubuntu-Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

The only way, for me, to solve this was by creating a cronjob.

```
@reboot systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

This was on a Dell XPS-13 9333